# Disable Shutdown prompt or solve it that it won't show

Tags: macos, xcode, osx-server, server.app, shutdown

Shen shutting down my computer, I see a prompt with information that another user is logged in and that this user could lose data when I shutdown computer:

[image: Shutdown prompt]

I am almost certain it's because I installed OS X Server and I connected to it with Xcode. I have it on my MacBook for work. How can I fix this? What causes this, and have I set something wrong? I just don't want to write my credentials everytime I want shutdown the computer but I don't want to lose any data.

Comment: Could you pick a stack exchange site to post to & not cross-post.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/183450/disable-os-x-servers-shutdown-prompt)

Answer (score 1):

> this user could loose data

Then they had better tighten the data up.

> when I shutdown computer

Don't. Just close the lid. If it is plugged in, background processes (like XCode compilation) will still run. If not, it's their problem and if it is XCode that particular process will simply fail and get processed elsewhere.

There is really no need to shut down a Mac daily. Mine only get powered down for disassembly-level maintenance, and only get rebooted for updates.

Comment: I don't have another user logged to my computer. So this must be some "user" which Server logged in (I don't know) for what purpose. I just quit (Cmd + Q) all apps (Xcode and Server too) and I don't what else there should be close for shutdown computer. Maybe I should change my habit and at end of day just close the lid as you wrote. Just doesn't feel right.

Comment: There _is_ a need to reboot macs every now and then. My Office's MacBook Air trackpad tend not to register multi-finger scrolls and swipes if not rebooted every few days.